# Failed to created JLineReader (Scala REPL)

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

When I start the REPL on Windows 7 64-bit (it works ok on my Windows XP laptop) I get the following message:

```
Failed to created JLineReader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initial
ize class org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32
Falling back to SimpleReader.
```

This means history and code completion don't work.

I have googled the problem but I can't find any resolution. I don't have sbt or Maven or ivy installed so I don't think it's anything to do with those. My %SCALA_HOME% is set up correctly.

There is something about a dependency on Scala 2.8 in this thread: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/9855, but I don't understand how to resolve this on my system.

As per suggestions in this thread: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/9795 I have updated my MS C++ libraries, but still have the problem. I ran the code suggested in post #11 and get the following:

```
scala> println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"))

C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\
Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;c:\Program F
iles (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Win
dows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files
(x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ZipGenius 6\;C:\Program Files (
x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files\apache-
ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\Program Files (x
86)\Notepad++;C:\Program Files (x86)\groovy-1.7.10\bin;C:\Program Files\scala2.9
\bin

scala> println(org.fusesource.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.getConsoleMode)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.fusesource.jansi.
internal.Kernel32
        at org.fusesource.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.getConsoleMode(WindowsSu
pport.java:48)
        at .<init>(<console>:8)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:11)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $export(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:592)

        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$10.apply(IMain.sca
la:828)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:4
3)
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:31)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help in getting this to work appreciated!

Comment: @Daniel Normal way with the Izpack installer

Comment: Mmmmm. Try to install through Typesafe's installer: it seems to be smarter than izpack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Solution was to type `del %TEMP%\jansi.dll` - see huynhjl's comment below for reason.

---

It seems the REPL is incompatible with the 64-bit JRE. I changed my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in Advanced System Settings to use the 32-bit version, i.e from `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_22`.

Then I had to correct the bug (that is STILL there) in the `scala.bat` file by changing line 24 from

```
    if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set _JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
```

to

```
    if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set "_JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
```

and it works OK now.

`java` from the command line is smart enough to use the 64-bit runtime regardless of your Path or JAVA_HOME variables, but `scala` uses whatever you specify in JAVA_HOME (which actually is probably the way it should be). But the 64-bit runtime is a lot faster than the 32-bit one, so I would like to use that.

At the moment it looks like I have to choose between a fully functional REPL and running on a 64-bit JVM. :(

Comment: I have a theory, but I'm not in front of my win64 install to validate it. There are two `jansi.dll` bundled in `jline.jar`, one for 32 bits and one for 64 bits. The one being picked up is chosen based on the value of `sun.arch.data.model` system property (32 or 64). Once unpacked the dll does not get refreshed based on timestamp. So my guess is that you first ran the 32 bits version which unpacked the 32 bits dll. When starting the 64 bits JVM, `jansi.dll` is incompatible. So try `del %TEMP%\jansi.dll` and then start your scala on 64 bits to see if that works.

Comment: I've submitted the following issue in the issue tracker: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4703