# REPL does not show input

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to write some Scala code in the Scala interpreter, using the following steps. I'm using Windows.

1. Open command prompt and go to project root directory
2. Type sbt then console to start Scala REPL
3. It opens the Scala REPL with below message

Message:

```
D:\example\example>sbt
"C:\Users\rajnish.kumar\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.4"\jars\sbt.jar"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from D:\example\example\project
[info] Set current project to bigdata-example (in build file:/D:/example/example/)

> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class scala.tools.fusesource_embedded.jansi.internal.Kernel32
        at scala.tools.fusesource_embedded.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.getConsoleMode(WindowsSupport.java:50)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.WindowsTerminal.getConsoleMode(WindowsTerminal.java:204)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.WindowsTerminal.init(WindowsTerminal.java:82)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:158)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:229)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:221)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:209)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline_embedded.JLineConsoleReader.<init>(JLineReader.scala:62)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline_embedded.InteractiveReader.<init>(JLineReader.scala:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$instantiater$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:858)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$instantiater$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:855)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$mkReader$1(ILoop.scala:862)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$21$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(ILoop.scala:873)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$21$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(ILoop.scala:873)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$21.apply(ILoop.scala:873)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$21.apply(ILoop.scala:873)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1233)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1223)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.collect(Stream.scala:435)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.chooseReader(ILoop.scala:875)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$2.apply(ILoop.scala:914)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:914)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:934)
        at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:101)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:76)
        at sbt.Console.sbt$Console$$console0$1(Console.scala:22)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:85)
        at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>
```

Now when I type anything (e.g. `val s = 30`) it do not appears in the command window. But when I hit enter it displays `scala> s: Int = 30`

My Scala version is 2.11.8.

Comment: There's an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361067/failed-to-created-jlinereader-scala-repl) similar to this. I'm not sure what's causing your problem, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Is it this assignement project - https://github.com/TomLous/coursera-scala-spark-big-data ?