# Scala REPL no echo on input

Tags: scala, sbt

There is a very strange problem with my scala REPL these days that it doesn't echo any input in the terminal.

Tried to remove ~/.sbt but didn't work. Using Ubuntu 18.04 and sbt 1.15.

Any one has similar issues?

Comment: Almost exactly the same question was posed in the last week or so (can't find it right now), but at least it seems that you're not alone with that problem. Google search for "scala repl does not show input" gives a few hits, maybe something [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9434), [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2090), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47866332/repl-does-not-show-input-windows) is useful?

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with scala 2.11.1. I have two scala versions on my workstation and the default was using the older one. Things worked after I updated everything to 2.12.6.

Comment: I think it would still be good if you posted it as your own answer, eventually marking it as "community wiki". Want to have something to redirect duplicates to.

Answer (score 18):

Had the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04. It seems certain Scala versions including 2.11.12 aren't compatible. I was able to get the REPL working properly on version 2.11.8.

To get that version use the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove scala-library scala
$ sudo wget www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.11.8.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.8.deb
```

Comment: This worked for me until I used `sudo apt upgrade`, at which point the problem came back.

Comment: Did work for me.  However, the other answer from Loki seems to be a better long term solution

Answer (score 13):

This seems to be an issue with JLine2 being built with JDK9+, but being used on JDK8.  If you're on bionic, try this PPA for jline2: https://launchpad.net/~lokkju/+archive/ubuntu/java-compat/

(or just download and install https://launchpad.net/~lokkju/+archive/ubuntu/java-compat/+build/16458066/+files/libjline2-java_2.14.6-1ubuntu1~bionicppa1_all.deb via dpkg)

You can verify jline2 is the problem by running `scala -Ydebug`, and looking for ByteBuffer class not found error.

I've also submitted bugs to hopefully address this issue in the future.

Comment: For me: `sudo apt install libjline2-java` after activating the ppa.

Answer (score 5):

Scala 2.11.1 has some compatibility issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04. Everything works after updating Scala/sbt to latest version.

Comment: to do this I needed to go to the "archived" section of the scala install page and download and install the v2.13 .deb package to upgrade